# How to retrieve specific character positions within rows of database column using REGEX in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

What Oracle SQL query could return the second, third and fourth positions of characters contained within rows of a specific column using the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` method instead of using `SUBSTR` method like my example provided below?

```
SELECT SUBSTR(city,2,3) AS "2nd, 3rd, 4th"
FROM student.zipcode;`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that works for me (with test data) is:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(city, '\S{3}', 2) AS partial FROM student.zipcode;
```

Note that this is set to find three non-whitespace characters beginning at the second position of the string.

You could also use:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(city, '.{3}', 2) AS partial FROM student.zipcode;
```

which will instead match any three characters in the 2nd to 4th position.

However, I'm not sure what advantage this has over simply:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(city,2,3) AS partial FROM student.zipcode;
```

The `REGEXP_INSTR` function is not what you want, as it returns an index (position number) for the search item in the searched string. You can read about it here: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_instr.php

Comment: `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 43`

Comment: Change alias or double quote it, e.g. SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(city, '.{3}', 2) AS "2to4" FROM student.zipcode;

Comment: I re-clarified question by editing the SUBSTR clause; so it's now, `SELECT SUBSTR(city,2,3,4) AS "2nd, 3rd, 4th"
FROM student.zipcode;`.